# Tag merge? [aspmenu] and [aspmenu-control]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

As near as I can tell, both [aspmenu](/questions/tagged/aspmenu) and [aspmenu-control](/questions/tagged/aspmenu-control) are both being used for the same ASP.Net control. It seems appropriate that at the very least they be merged, and maybe placed under a new tag more in line with the naming of other ASP.Net control related tags?

Comment: I feel aspmenu should be the main one, because we also have [tag:asplinkbutton] and [tag:aspbutton]. Which other asp.net control related tags do you have in mind? I couldn't find anything else so quickly...

Comment: I created the tag wiki for aspmenu as well...